# Snap store can't upgrade "snap-store" despite being prompted to

Tags: snap-store

How do I go around this? Do I have to install synaptic? I already upgraded via terminal.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update "Snap Store": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412546/unable-to-update-snap-store-null-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-s)

Answer (score 8):

You have to kill snap-store process and then upgrade snap-store in particular. Then run the refresh command.

```
sudo killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't update snap-store from within snap-store, because snap-store needs to be closed in order to update. Snaps should auto-update, so you should be able to just forget about it and let it do its thing when the time comes. But if you don't like to wait for an auto-update to finally show up, you can update it from the terminal:

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

Answer (score 1):

Most users don't need to do anything at all. Snapd will automatically update/refresh `snap-store` without any action needed by you.

Snapd checks for updates several times each day, including at startup.

Snap application updates cannot happen while the application is running, which is why `snap-store` cannot update itself. Simply Quit out of the `snap-store` application when you are done using it...and don't worry about it. Snapd will handle the update automatically.

For folks who really want to be hands-on:

1. Quit out of the application. Not minimize, not 'X' the window, it must be a real Quit. The application cannot be running.
2. `sudo snap refresh`. Wait for the command to complete.
3. (Optional) Re-launch the application.