# Unable to update "Snap Store": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: snap, 22.04

When I update snap store through Ubuntu Software Centre I get Following Error

Unable to update "Snap Store": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
killall snap-store
snap refresh
```

Comment: Ok it works. Still it's a shame that in the first minutes of running a fresh Ubuntu installation you already get an error that requires running commands to be fixed. Really not user-friendly.

Comment: What does the kill accomplish? Is it normal/necessary for `snap-store` to be running in the background? If not, why would it be? In my case, `snap refresh` worked without killing snap-store, even though I saw the OP's message for days.

Comment: Oh. I did get a temporary notification https://i.imgur.com/wsApxE6.png even though it says `All snaps up to date` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯