# Latest Snap Store version for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: snap-store

I´ve had the same issue as other people updating the Snap Store (just as this topic explains: [Unable to update "Snap Store": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412546/unable-to-update-snap-store-null-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-s)) on 22.04, and got it solved following the steps provided by other users: uninstalling and reinstalling Snap Store via terminal.

Now, my problem is the following: within the Ubuntu Software app, previous to solving this problem, it indicated that the Snap Store version installed that needed to be updated was on 41.3-59 -but, after solving this issue reinstalling Snap Store via terminal, it states that the new version installed is 3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7. So:

**Old version: 41.3-59**

**New version: 3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7**

Judging by the numbers, looks like the new version is indeed older than the oudated version :S

I´m a complete newbie in the Linux world. Tried to find any source that tells which Snap Store version is the latest available, but couldn´t find anything. Can someone please explain the reason of this behavior? I´m sure it´s all about my ignorance, but would be immensely grateful if someone could give a little help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look with `snap info`:

```bash
$ snap info snap-store
name:    snap-store
summary: Snap Store is a graphical desktop application for discovering, installing and managing
  snaps on Linux.
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/snap-store

 
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/
license:   GPL-2.0+
description: |
  Snap Store showcases featured and popular applications with useful descriptions, ratings, reviews
  and screenshots.
  
  
  Applications can be found either through browsing categories
  or by searching.
  
  
  Snap Store can also be used to switch channels, view and alter snap permissions and view and
  submit reviews and ratings.
  
  
  Snap Store is based on GNOME Software, optimized for the Snap experience.
snap-id: gjf3IPXoRiipCu9K0kVu52f0H56fIksg
channels:
  latest/stable:    3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7  2021-11-22 (558) 56MB -
  latest/candidate: 3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7  2022-03-28 (558) 56MB -
  latest/beta:      3.38.0-67-g78a06f78 2022-04-28 (579) 56MB -
  latest/edge:      41.3-62-g960b074    2022-05-19 (585) 48MB -
```

Version `3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7` is the stable version which should be installed, snap defaults to the stable channel.

It appears that in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 the edge version is installed, I'd think this is a bug.

However, we can install the version of our choice:

```
snap install snap-store            # for stable version
snap install snap-store --edge     # for edge version
```

Comment: Hi @mook756, thanks for answering! Turns out, not only me but *everyone* who I have read that has installed 22.04 from scratch has 41.3-59 version by default (take a look at the screenshot of topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412546/unable-to-update-snap-store-null-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-s. I have seen the exact same screens in another forums discussing this issue. BTW the version displayed at the Ubuntu Software app in the screenshot states the current installed version, not the version to be installed). That´s why I find this version thing so confusing...

Comment: Yep, I had installed fresh 22.04 and had the 41.3.59 version. I removed it and installed stable and it seems right.  This should be marked as answer.  thanks